# How to insert data with a field that contains a '

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am appending to a table data from a recordset, which is working, until I get a French client that has a ' in his client name. Here is the code:

```
StrSQL3 = " INSERT INTO [ATB] ( SLSMAN, NOCARDEX, email, CLIENT, "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " NOTRANS, InvoiceDate, Current, [31-60], [61-90], [90+] ) "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " VALUES ( '" & myRecordSet.Fields(0).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(1).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(2).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(3).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(4).Value & "',  "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(5).Value & "',  "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(6).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(7).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(8).Value & "', "
StrSQL3 = StrSQL3 & " '" & myRecordSet.Fields(9).Value & "' ) "
    If OldEmail = email Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL3
```

It all works great, until I Get this client:Location D'Outils Nicolet.
Because of the ' in the client name, I get error 3075 - Missing operator.

Does anyone out there know a way around this?

Comment: Does VBA support parameterized SQL? Because that's the way to go here...

Answer (score 3):

The quotes are not a problem when you use a parameter query.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strInsert As String

strInsert = "INSERT INTO [ATB] (" & vbCrLf & _
    "SLSMAN, NOCARDEX, email, CLIENT, " & _
    "NOTRANS, InvoiceDate, [Current], " & _
    "[31-60], [61-90], [90+])" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES (p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9);"
Debug.Print strInsert

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("p0").value = MyRecordSet.Fields(0).value
qdf.Parameters("p1").value = MyRecordSet.Fields(1).value
' add the remaining parameter values
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: It's worth noting that as well as solving the problem, parameterised queries also solve [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thank you Hans for the prompt response. I am unclear as to what is